# how do I start this pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

ok I am lost right now by this assignment and just need some help.

The assignment is Design a program that generates the sum of numbers.

Given a number (user input) you need an application that will produce a sum of the numbers from 1 to that given number I just need some help to start because I am just having to hard of a time and i know it might seem easy but never had any experience to any of this at all.

Comment: Would this be Correct for this Assignment or is there something I am missing

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = getUserInput;
var sum;

while (input > 0)
{
  sum = sum + input--;
}

print sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something as straightforward as this:

```
input = getuserInput()
count = 0
sum = 0
while count < input:
    count = count + 1
    sum = sum + count

return sum
```

...then enhance it.

Comment: I am sorry but how would i go on to enhance it

Comment: For example, there are more variables than needed. You can handle/convert bad user input values too.

Comment: ok thanks it has been very stressful on understanding on the whole pseudocode thing and have been looking everywhere online just to get some help on answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
INPUT number 
VARIABLE sum = 0
FOR VARIABLE n = 1 TO number WITH STEP 1 DO
    sum += n
END FOR
PRINT sum
```

Translated to lua it would look like this:

```
number = tonumber( io.read() )
sum = 0
for n = 1, number, 1 do
    sum = sum + n
end
print(sum)
```

Translated into python it would look like

```
Number = int(input("Number:"))
Sum = 0
for n in range(1,Number+1):
    Sum += n
print(Sum)
```

Though the pythonic way would resemble:

```
number = int(input("Number:"))
print(sum(range(number+1)))
```

When applying this to any language look out for the following:

1. Converting the user's input to an ***integer***, by default it will normally be a string i.e `"..."`.
2. Declare a variable to hold the total (in our case `sum`) before you try to add a number to it i.e `n`.
3. Make sure your for loop goes from **1** *to* ***number***

Comment: So by doing this one then I would only put Declare Sum as interger and Declare Number as float and just setting the Sum=0 am I doing that right.

Comment: @AnibalZuniga You would want to declare both as integers. However you also want to assign `Sum` a value of 0. Sum needs to be set to `0` because you use it later on when you go `sum = sum + n` for the first time (when n will equal 1), if you don't set `sum` to `0` before it would be like saying `sum = null+ n` and you can't add null to n.

Comment: So how would you go on writing a iteration structure because I got and it probably is wrong its goes ELSE Set Sum=Sum+Number end if not sure if that is wrong or not

Comment: You shouldn't need an else because there isn't a condition like `if something is true then do this else do that`, you want a `for` loop which iterates over the integers between 1 and `number`. What language are you using?

Comment: Well im taking IT/210 and its saying I need to have a iteration structure so I am trying to see if im doing this right

Comment: @AnibalZuniga You can use either a `while`,`do while`,`for` loop to accomplish this task. However I would recommend using a `for` loop as it is the most readable. You will want something along the lines of `for(int i = 0; i <= number; i++){ ... }`

Comment: so you would use a pretest loop.